# Number of hcf between two numbers

Tags: java

I want to print the number of hcf between two numbers using scanner class.I tried this code, this is giving an error.How can same be done by using file handling.

```
Execution failed.
java.util.NoSuchElementException : No line found
Stack Trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:13)  


  import java.util.*;
 class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {      

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num1 = s.nextLine();  
     String num2 = s.nextLine(); 
    int n1 =Integer.parseInt(num1);
    int n2 =Integer.parseInt(num2);      

    int max=0;
    int gcd = 1;
    if (n1<=n2)
    {
        max=n1;
    }
        else {
            max=n2;
        }
        int count=0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= max; ++i)
    {
        if((n1%i==0) && (n2%i==0))
        gcd=i;
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println(" "+ count);
}
}
```

Comment: It can’t find the input line, how are executing it?

Comment: This code doesn't match exception (at least based on lines numbers). Also `NoSuchElementException: No line found` suggests that `System.in` may be closed (which doesn't happen in this code). How does your real code looks like, or how are you using current one?

Comment: You need to revise your question.  A pair of numbers has exactly one highest common factor (HCF).  What you are doing is trying to count all of the common factors.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that the program will give you that exception is if you run it with an input file with less than two lines in it.

Now it *may be* that you are supposed to read an input file with one line consisting of two numbers.  If so, you should be using `nextInt` rather than `nextLine`, and dispensing with the step where you call `parseInt`.

---

Once you have gotten past the "input" problem, there is another problem in your code:

```
    if((n1%i==0) && (n2%i==0))
    gcd=i;
    count++;
```

Hint #1:  what is the purpose of the `gcd` variable?

Hint #2:  where does the `if` statement end?

Hint #3:  proper indentation and use of curly brackets are very important ...

Answer (score 0):

```
            package Loops;

            import java.util.Scanner;

            public class Question10 {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                while (x < 0 || y < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the postive numbers: ");
                    x = sc.nextInt();
                    y = sc.nextInt();
                }
                int z = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                    if (x % i == 0 && y % i == 0) {
                        z = i;

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Hcf is: " + z);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num1 = s.nextLine();
        String num2 = s.nextLine();

        int n1 =Integer.parseInt(num1);
        int n2 =Integer.parseInt(num2);

        int min = n1;
        int max = n2;
        if (n2<n1){min = n2; max = n1;}

        int hfc = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= min;) {
            if (min%i == 0 && max%i == 0) {
                min = min / i;
                max = max / i;
                hfc = hfc * i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```